# Prompt a like input Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, command

Hello Im doing a little project and I would like to do a input commands that work something similar to prompt().

```
$('.form-me').on('submit', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 if($(input).val() === "comand") {
  var value1 = prompt("insert something");
  var value2 = prompt("insert something");
 }
});
```

The thing is, that I don't want to use prompt() but I would like to have an information print out above input, and after inputting first value I will get an next print above input and input the second value. I've though about it for quite a while and can't find an solution to get some kind of step-by-step value inputing. Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: Not certain what you mean by _"have an information print out above input"_? The text which user input at `$(input)` element? Can you include `html` at Question? Where is `input` defined?

Comment: There is no something similar to prompt only custom solutions.

One solution you can build your own dialogue. Some div with input and button above everything